# Possession 's form and articles

Tags: articles, possessives

I am starting my question with the Wikipedia page on [Young's modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_modulus) and its usage of the possessive 's form on the proper name Young. According to me, the text starts well with the definition of *Young's modulus* also called *the Young modulus*. However, further below on the page, (section: Temperature dependence), we can read *The Young's modulus of metals*.

This is where my question is: is it acceptable to concatenate the possessive form *Young's modulus* with the definite article *The* (or any other article)?

Below are my personal views on this:

1. For the mechanical system of interest, Young's modulus is set to 10 MPa [Correct]
2. For the mechanical system of interest, the Young modulus is set to 10 MPa [Correct/Preferred]
3. For the mechanical system of interest, the Young's modulus is set to 10 MPa [Wrong]

More generally, we sometimes see two successive possessive forms:

1. The system's Young's modulus is set to 10 MPa [Wrong]
2. The Young modulus of the system of interest is set to 10 MPa [Correct/Preferred]
3. Young's modulus of the system of interest is set to 10 MPa [Correct (not too sure)]

What are the correct practices on the above examples?

Comment: [Punctuation](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf) is not a part of English grammar; it's determined by printers and publishers and changes erratically.  Consequently there is no consensus on usages, though there is no shortage of rules, mostly arbitrary and contradictory. In any event, [mathematical notation](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-MathematicalNotation.pdf) is not subject to outside rules. Mathematicians make their own rules. Though you might check the editing discussion on Wikipedia; you may not have been the first to notice this.

Comment: Wikipedia can be edited by almost anyone, and there's no editors checking for consistent style in most entries.

Comment: @Barmar I agree but this Wikipedia page was used as an illustrative example. The usage of the possessive form (Young's) as an adjective is still unclear to me.

Comment: @pluton My general point is that this is something that people are not consistent about. And the Wikipedia page is a perfect example of that -- different editors used a different style.